# Обойтись 1-им запросом

Tags: mysql, php, sql

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT `tid`, `tcategory`, `turl`, `tname`, `tfile_text`, `tcount`, `tprice`, `tdone_users`, `trepost`, `tcomments` FROM `tasks` WHERE `tvk_id` != $vk_id AND `tdel` != 1 AND `tsuccess` = 0 AND `tid` NOT IN($tasks_done) ORDER BY `tprice` DESC LIMIT $start_ent, 50");

$num = $db->num($db->query("SELECT `tid` FROM `tasks` WHERE `tvk_id` != $vk_id AND `tdel` != 1 AND `tsuccess` = 0 AND `tid` NOT IN($tasks_done)"));
```

Как можно сделать проще, чтобы всё подсчитать 1 запросом и за одно вывести 50 записей? А то какой-то двойной запрос получается...

Comment: А если в первый запрос просто добавить COUNT(`tid`) AS `cnt`? Или под "*всё подсчитать*", вы имели в виду что-то другое?

Comment: @Deonis, так оно ведь будет 50 показывать, даже если материалов 150. LIMIT 50 же...

Comment: мне одному подобные записи кажутся нечитабельными? или я просто привык к отступам...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, я не внимательно сначала просмотрел.

В общем, можно так сделать:

```
$query = "SELECT 
    t1.`tid`, t1.`tcategory`, t1.`turl`, t1.`tname`, t1.`tfile_text`, t1.`tcount`, t1.`tprice`, t1.`tdone_users`, t1.`trepost`, t1.`tcomments`, t3.`cnt`
FROM 
    `tasks` t1 JOIN
(SELECT COUNT(t2.`tid`) AS `cnt` FROM `tasks` t2 WHERE t2.`tvk_id` != $vk_id AND t2.`tdel` != 1 AND t2.`tsuccess` = 0 AND t2.`tid` NOT IN($tasks_done)) t3
WHERE 
 `t1.`tvk_id` != $vk_id AND t1.`tdel` != 1 AND t1.`tsuccess` = 0 AND t1.`tid` NOT IN($tasks_done) ORDER BY t1.`tprice` DESC LIMIT $start_ent, 50";
```

Только на мой взгляд, не особо много смысла в этом.

Comment: @Deonis, странно. Но ваш SELECT COUNT(*) AS `cnt` сработал при LIMIT 50 и стало выдавать всё: >> SELECT COUNT(*) AS `cnt` FROM `tasks` WHERE `tvk_id` != $vk_id AND `tdel` != 1 AND `tsuccess` = 0 AND `tid` NOT IN($tasks_done) ORDER BY `tprice` DESC LIMIT $start_ent, 50

но проблема теперь другая. как мне получить данные которые нужно? например `tid`, `tname`? COUNT(`tid`) отказал :(